# Como bloquear caracteres especiais em um campo textarea

Tags: javascript, html

A questão é o seguinte, eu apliquei uma máscara em todos em todos os inputs, que nega a entrada de qualquer caractere não permitido, até ai tudo bem, o problema são os campos textarea, já pesquei muito e não obtive sucesso em bloquear certos caracteres nele, dado que esse tipo de campo não aceita o atributo pattern do HTML 5.

```js
// DEFINE A MÁSCARA PARA INPUTS

function maskCharacters(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp('[^ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b@,.]', 'g');            
    $('input').bind('input', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
  });
}
```

```css
.support {
     max-width: 250px;
     height: auto;
}

.support input, .support textarea{
     width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="support">
  <label>Input de Exemplo</label>
  <input type="text" onkeydown="return maskCharacters(event)"> 
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <label>Textarea de Exemplo *</label>
  <textarea name="message" rows="4" maxlength="350" required=""></textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Prevenção de SQL injection deve ser feita no backend. NUNCA deixe isso somente a cargo do frontend. Dito isso, se o texto não aceito, rejeite no backend e mostre mensagem amigável no frontend. Validar demais no frontend nunca é uma boa ideia e uma dor e cabeça...

Comment: Como eu disse, eu fiz isso essa prevenção usando PHP quando recebo os dados, eu preciso de algo visual para impedir que o usuário insira tais caracteres.

Comment: Já estou meio sem esperanças, eu posso recorrer a uma mensagem de aviso perfeitamente, mas ai fugiria do que eu tinha em mente.

Comment: Então, se você fez a validação no backend, em termos de segurança, tu não ganha nada com a validação no frontend. Entendo que tu queira já validar a entrada do usuário no textarea, mas não ache que seja uma boa ideia. SQL injections costumam ser enviados por Request via console/terminal, não diretamente no form da página. DE qualquer jeito, só falta adicionar a lógica do input pro textarea tb, adicionei a minha resposta.

Comment: achei que a pergunta tinha ficado ruim, então decidi apagar.

Comment: Mas vou dar uma olhada na pergunta você citou.

Comment: Na verdade, acho que vou reperguntar, mas sendo mais direto agora.

Answer (score 2):

Na sua função `maskCharacters`, você estava indicando que ela deveria retornar com o valor validado apenas nos `$(input)`, sem indicar o `textarea` junto.

Você também não precisa utilizar o `bind`, basta adicionar um evento nos elementos que quer que sejam validados:

```js
function maskCharacters() {
  
      var regex = new RegExp('[^ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b@,.]', 'g');            
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
}

$('textarea, input').keyup(maskCharacters);
```

```css
.support {
     max-width: 250px;
     height: auto;
}

.support input, .support textarea{
     width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="support">
  <label>Input de de Exemplo</label>
  <input type="text"> 
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <label>Textarea de Exemplo *</label>
  <textarea name="message" rows="4" maxlength="350" required=""></textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 1):

Indique no seletor jQuery que tu quer aplicar a função blacklist no textarea também, and adicione

```
$('input,textarea').bind('input', function(){
```

e adicione o binding da função externa no textarea:

```
onkeydown="return maskCharacters(event)"
```

```js
// DEFINE A MÁSCARA PARA INPUTS

function maskCharacters(e) {
    var regex = new RegExp('[^ 0-9a-zA-Zàèìòùáéíóúâêîôûãõ\b@,.]', 'g');            
    $('input,textarea').bind('input', function(){
    $(this).val($(this).val().replace(regex, ''));
  });
}
```

```css
.support {
     max-width: 250px;
     height: auto;
}

.support input, .support textarea{
     width: 250px;
}
```

```html
<div class="support">
  <label>Input de de Exemplo</label>
  <input type="text" onkeydown="return maskCharacters(event)"> 
  
  <br>
  <br>
  
  <label>Textarea de Exemplo *</label>
  <textarea name="message" rows="4" maxlength="350" required=""  onkeydown="return maskCharacters(event)"></textarea>
</div>

<script src="https://code.jquery.com/jquery-3.2.1.slim.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Valeu cara, funcionou perfeito!